# C# run process as different user from file server

Tags: c#, winforms, process, runas, fileserver

I'm trying to run an executable from a file server, I first tried making a test application with only that functionality. That worked perfectly (let's refer to it as `APP1`), but then I moved it over to a Windows Forms (that would be `APP2`), I kept getting `Invalid Directory` or `File Not Found` errors.

This is the code I used:

```
var sspw = new SecureString();

foreach (var c in "MyPassword")
    sspw.AppendChar(c);

ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                FileName = @"\\MyServer\MySharedDirectory\MyFolder\usernametest.exe",
                Arguments = "",
                Domain = "MyDomain",
                UserName = "SomeUser",
                Password = sspw
            };
```

The application I'm running is a simple application I made that displays the username of the user running it. I have tried setting the working directory and filename individually, but that did not help.

When I tried `APP1`, it worked with 2 different users from my domain. When I run the Windows Forms app, it passes through the login, so login appears OK (putting a wrong password gives me wrong pw error) but then the mentioned errors appear.

EDIT: I found out what the diffrence where, `APP1` runs from my local computer, while `APP2` is located just one level above the executable that i'm trying to run(AKA on the same file server), what difference does it make to run the application from a file server, rather than my local computer?

Comment: Perhaps the error message is correct and the path is simply wrong? Or the user doesn't have permissions to the shared folder?

Comment: Then i can't see a reason for the first application working? And i've checked the path and have tried running the file, both users are system administrators

Comment: why not? You are mixing different accounts, working on different machines. Why do you assume that a straightforward error message is wrong? Did you at least check the event logs? Activate access auditing on the share's (or directory's) security properties and check for access failures in the Security event log.

Comment: My tests are both on my machine, and both users worked in application 1, then i copyed the code to application 2, and the same code did not work. not sure if i'm following you here?

Comment: The `invalid directory` and `file not found` errors are more likely given by the application itself, so you need to look where is the application looking for the files. I suspect an error in the working directory, but since you said you specified it, I need to trust you on this (since it's not shown on the question)

Comment: I'm starting to doubt my working directory settings, when launching an application form a file server, what should Working Directory be set to? I've tried both localy, in the same folder as the exe and several other locations

Comment: Well, you must know what the correct working directory should be. Presumably, the executable you're trying to run is searching for some files on a relative path. Setting it to the same directory as the exe is the same way this works when you just run the exe from e.g. Explorer.